# Sims 4 thumbnail error

Tags: technical-issues, the-sims-4

I've been having some issues with the Sims 4. My thumbnails are constantly glitching up, and it's quite a nuisance. This has happened in the previous games, too -- so I'm not sure if it's my computer, or what.

Here are my specs:

```
Windows XP Home Edition, SP3
Pentium Dual Core CPU E400 @ 2.70GHz
2.69GHz, 2.00 GB of RAM
ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series
DirectX 9.0c
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to **My Documents** -> **Electronic Arts** -> **The Sims 4**  (or wherever you store your games)

Delete the **Cache** directory and the **localthumbcache** file.

Launch Sims 4 again and the problem should be fixed. This happened to me a while ago too.

Comment: I did that, and I'm still getting the same issues. Just to make sure, I even deleted my tray. I'm getting seriously irritated at this matter.

Comment: Also, I'm missing a cache folder, it looks like.

Comment: Weird. These steps fixed it for me when I ran into this problem. Maybe add an empty cache folder and an empty text file called localthumbcache. Reboot, and restart the game to see if it starts writing there again?

Answer (score -1):

Diagnose DEP issues:

1. Open System Properties dialog box.
   a. Right click Computer.
   b. Select Properties.
   c. Click Advanced system settings.
2. Open DEP-related settings.
   a. Click Settings (Performance) > Data Execution Prevention.
3. Exclude EXE:
   a. Add all the files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\Game\Bin
   b. Click OK, do reboot.

If you need more solutions please do visit [here](http://pcfresher.com/blog/sims-4-crashing-in-pc-can-be-avoided-here-is-how/):

Comment: Why does this solve the issue?  I'm not seeing anything in the question that would point to DEP being the issue.